# Keras Upsampling2d vs PyTorch Upsampling

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, dimensions

I am trying to convert a Keras Model to PyTorch. Now, it involves the `UpSampling2D` from `keras`. When I used `torch.nn.UpsamplingNearest2d` in pytorch, as default value of `UpSampling2D` in keras is `nearest`, I got different inconsistent results. The example is as follows:

**Keras behaviour**

```py
In [3]: t1 = tf.random_normal([32, 8, 8, 512]) # as we have channels last in keras                                  

In [4]: u_s = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(2)(t1)                               

In [5]: u_s.shape                                                               
Out[5]: TensorShape([Dimension(32), Dimension(16), Dimension(16), Dimension(512)])
```

So the output shape is `(32,16,16,512)`. Now let's do the same thing with PyTorch.

**PyTorch Behaviour**

```py
In [2]: t1 = torch.randn([32,512,8,8]) # as channels first in pytorch

In [3]: u_s = torch.nn.UpsamplingNearest2d(2)(t1)

In [4]: u_s.shape
Out[4]: torch.Size([32, 512, 2, 2])
```

Here output shape is `(32,512,2,2)` as compared to `(32,512,16,16)` from keras.

So how do I get equvivlent results of Keras in PyTorch. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keras, it uses a scaling factor to upsample. [SOURCE](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/UpSampling2D).

```
tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size, interpolation='nearest')
```

> size: Int, or tuple of 2 integers. The upsampling factors for rows and columns.

And, PyTorch provides, both, direct **output size** and **scaling factor**. [SOURCE](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.UpsamplingNearest2d.html).

```
torch.nn.UpsamplingNearest2d(size=None, scale_factor=None)
```

> To specify the scale, it takes either the size or the scale_factor as its constructor argument.

---

So, in your case

```
# scaling factor in keras 
t1 = tf.random.normal([32, 8, 8, 512])
tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(2)(t1).shape
TensorShape([32, 16, 16, 512])

# direct output size in pytorch 
t1 = torch.randn([32,512,8,8]) # as channels first in pytorch
torch.nn.UpsamplingNearest2d(size=(16, 16))(t1).shape
# or torch.nn.UpsamplingNearest2d(size=16)(t1).shape
torch.Size([32, 512, 16, 16])

# scaling factor in pytorch.
torch.nn.UpsamplingNearest2d(scale_factor=2)(t1).shape
torch.Size([32, 512, 16, 16])
```